# MySQL Select a range of letters

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove the letters between the first two letters and the last two letters? Is it something like a combination of `LIKE` and `=<>` ?

Table Name: Items_ordered

```
OrderDate      Item
------------------------
2015-07-01     Skateboard
2015-07-01     Life Vest
2015 -07-06    Parachute
2015-07-27     Umbrella
```

Sample Output:

```
OrderDate      Item
--------------------
2015-07-01     Skrd
2015-07-01     List
2015-07-06    Pate
2015-07-27     Umla
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Your google search string is `MySQL string functions`.

Comment: Look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: @DariaPydorenko Doesn't quite warrant a regexp

Answer (score 1):

Use left() and right()

```
select OrderDate, concat(left(Item,2), right(Item,2) )as NewItem
from Items_ordered
```

However, what happens with an item like 'Bag', with less than 4 letters?

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: @JohnConde I disagree that this is not MCVE. OP has explained table structure and desired output and has shown some level of what they tried

Comment: Where do they show what they've tried? There literally is no SQL in their question nor do they describe what they tried.